# Upgrade project for iPhone X and iOS 11

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, ios11, xcode9, iphone-x

I'm working on very old project which is written in objective-C and it's all views and controllers are written programatically. (There are not even XIBs, except some cells)

I've already open project in latest Xcode 9.3 and resolve all error and dependencies and compiled it successfully.

But now I want to upgrade the whole project to give support for **iOS 11 and iPhone X** layout, and I also want to add storyboards and remove all programatically controllers. It's also compatible for iPad and iPhone both.

Can anyone suggest me how to start it and what to keep in mind?
It's huge project so I'm bit confuse either would I make it or not. (I don't wanna introduce **swift** at the moment, first I'll update it for iPhone X layout and storyboards, then I'll think about swift too)

Comment: if you have a working gui created programmatically... why change it? You may just need to adjust code e.g. add constraints for responsiveness. A storyboard is not required... imho

Comment: yeah that's also true but actually I want to upgrade my code according to [new requirements by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=05072018a)  so it supports iOS 11 and iPhone X both properly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all start with creating UI on storyboard with autolayout. 
Remove the resizing views conditions from the code.
Use size class to support both iPhone and iPad.
so basically first 3 steps will solve 70% of your issues.
My suggestion is don't move to the swift before doing all this.

Comment: ok thanks. It's a huge codebase and there are lots of connections in navigations so it'll be hard to switch into storyboard. but I'll try as you suggested.